# How to reset form after successful Submission having float type Entity?

Tags: c#

I have a view model like:

```
public class CompanyAccountViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public float Interval { get; set; }
    public List<string> MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

I clear the model after successful submission as follows:

```
modelState.Clear();
viewModel = new CompanyAccountViewModel();
```

All input field is cleared except `Interval`. Interval Field is populated with ZERO(0) value. Any idea?

Comment: Yes. All fields is set to defaults and 0 is default value of float. And what do you expect? What value should be set?

Comment: That's default behavior for non-nullable numeric value type, it always set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize the value to anything else than zero, you have to use a datatype that allows an "empty" value. In case of `float` this would be `Nullable<float>` which can also be written `float?`:

```
public class CompanyAccountViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public float? Interval { get; set; }
    public List<string> MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to keep this field not null able and remove this default value(ZERO)

Comment: if you want a default value different than 0 just do `public float? Interval { get; set; } = defaultValue` otherwise no value is the purpose of `null` so it's meant to be done with `Nullable<>`